# Border too wide because of margin

Tags: css, navigation, border

I have an inline unordered list as navigation bar in my html. I wanted a top border to show up when hovering on li element. But when I add margin or padding to make some space between consecutive elements, the border is too wide. I don't want to add spaces in html. Is there any other way? I tried putting an empty div with defined width but it didn't work. The best result I could get was with text-decoration overline, but unfortunately i need a different color than black. Here's my code:

```
LI
{
display: inline;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.2em;
padding-left: 30px;
}
LI:hover
{
border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

and HTML

```
<ul>
            <a href="#"><li>link 1</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>link 2</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>link 3</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>link 4</li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: I would recommend floating all the elements inside the list and making it displayed as blocks. Inline lists are hard to decipher at times - however, post your code. Let's see it

Comment: I added my code, maybe you see some easier solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding extends the width of your elements while margin creates empty spacing after and before the element. You may want to read more about [Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

I adjusted my code to better suit your case:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <a href="#"><li>link 1</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>link 2</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>link 3</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>link 4</li></a>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul a {
    text-decoration: none !important; //Removes default underline form link
}

li {
    display: inline;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    padding-left: 0.2em; // Letter spacing is making borders to extend slightly more on the right. This makes borders extend similarly on the left
    padding-top: 2px; //To push top border slightly higher, so that top and bottom is the same distance from your text
    margin-left: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent; //Stops navigation from extending on :hover
}

li:hover {
    border-top: 1px solid #000; //border top on :hover
}
```

FiddleJS: http://jsfiddle.net/kGN69/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly what I needed. But just to understand better - why is it necessery to make transparent border first? How does it affect the width of it on :hover?

Comment: It doesn't affect width of your items however it is a good practice to do so if you will be drawing a border on :hover state. If you wouldn't have this transparent border, browser would be pushing your item down by 1px (border thickness) when hovering, because it will have to allocate extra space above given element. It doesn't affect you code because you declared `display` to `inline` but it would on `inline-block` or `block` or if you would decide to add borders on the sides. Live example without and with transparent borders: http://jsfiddle.net/kGN69/5/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/kGN69/6/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using margin, try using Padding instead.

Can I see your coding...? It would be a lot easier.

First, are you making sure you are editing the li hover?

Example:

```
#yourdiv li a:hover{
.....
}
```

If you are, try change this.

Example:

```
#yourdiv{
...
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
}
```