# Border-bottom too wide

Tags: html, css

I've got this dropdownmenu for my site and I wanted to add border-bottom to the menu but the border appears too wide.
I've checked every step of: [Border too wide because of margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330456/border-too-wide-because-of-margin) because it seemed the same problem, but nothing worked.

Hope you can help me out!!

[image]

Here's de css code:

```
#dropdownmenu a {
        color:inherit !important;
        text-decoration:none !important}

#dropdownmenu {
        width:1050px;
        background:#137cd7;
        z-index:2;
        position:relative }
#dropdownmenu ul {
    text-align:left;
    display:inline;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px 4px 25px 0;
    list-style:none }
#dropdownmenu ul li {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-right:10px;
        position:relative;
        padding:15px 15px 14px;
        cursor:pointer;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.2s;
        -moz-transition:all 0.2s;
        -ms-transition:all 0.2s;
        -o-transition:all 0.2s;
        transition:all 0.2s;
        color:#fff }
#dropdownmenu ul li:hover {
        background-color:#ffffff;
        color:#137cd7 }

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)

#dropdownmenu ul li ul {
        top:44px !important}


#dropdownmenu ul li ul {
        padding:0px;
        position:absolute;
        top:47px;
        left:0px;
        width:170px;
        display:none;
        opacity:0;
        visibility:hidden;
        -webkit-transiton:opacity 0.2s;
        -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s;
        -ms-transition:opacity 0.2s;
        -o-transition:opacity 0.2s;
        -transition:opacity 0.2s }

#dropdownmenu ul li ul li {
        background-color:#fff;
        display:block;
        color:#222;
        border-left:1px solid #ccc;
        border-right:1px solid #ccc;}

#dropdownmenu ul li ul li:hover {
        color:#137cd7;
        background:#fff;
        text-decoration:none !important }

#dropdownmenu ul li:hover ul {
        display:block;
        opacity:1;
        visibility:visible;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="dropdownmenu">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/contact"><img alt="" src="/files/19731/editor/images/support(1).JPG" style="width: 140px; height: 140px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" /></a></li>
            <li>
                &nbsp;</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VLRUL/)

Thanks everyone!

I added this code which worked for me:
    #dropdownmenu ul li ul li { margin-right: 0;}

This one worked as well:
1) remove the border from #dropdownmenu ul li ul li {border-left:0; border-right:0} and add border to the #dropdownmenu ul li:hover ul {border:1px solid #ccc; border-top:0;}

Comment: Do you want something like that http://jsfiddle.net/ZvRER/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by:

```
#dropdownmenu ul li {
   margin-right:10px;
}
```

That margin is causing your dropdown menu to expand wider than it should. Try adding:

```
#dropdownmenu ul li ul li {
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRMmU/)

Comment: if those 10px margin are important to set, somehow, a width, they can be removed and be added to padding-right. http://jsfiddle.net/VLRUL/3/ useless, but to say margins to add width or keep some free space can be set from inside and or outside elements

Answer (score 1):

***[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/VLRUL/2/)***

Removed *border* style from here

```
#dropdownmenu ul li:hover ul
```

and added here

```
#dropdownmenu ul li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

CSS selector `:last-child` browser support [stat's here](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child)

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions you can take

1) remove the border from `#dropdownmenu ul li ul li {border-left:0; border-right:0}`
  and add border to the `#dropdownmenu ul li:hover ul {border:1px solid #ccc; border-top:0;}`

2) add border-bottom to the last element of `#dropdownmenu ul li ul li`
  `#dropdownmenu ul li ul li:last {border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}` if browser support is not an issue